# Which is safer in term of security, sending parameters thru url or JSON object?

Tags: security, url, http-post, http-get

Which is safer in term of security, sending parameters thru url or JSON object?

URL:

```
www.mywebsite.com/search.php?password=t45vye45vh
```

JSON object:

```
request.post(url, data);
```

Comment: For search or get request parameter is fine...

Comment: How abt if you are going to post username and pw?

Comment: Neither is secure in any meaningful sense, if you are worried about security http**s**://www.mywebsite.com

Answer (score 1):

> The GET method requests a representation of the specified resource.
>   Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have no other
>   effect.

Whenever user want to data from server using only basic details like userId or some other id then use get request.

> POST submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the
>   identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request.
>   This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of
>   existing resources or both.

Post method generally used for form or passing more number of data to server. Whenever something needs to store on server, post request is used. Eg. for registration, login, file upload, making new record etc.

Comment: Also, seeing GET adds to the URL on the next page, the page can be remembered by your browsers history, as well as search engines may include it as a separate page to one without the GET variable

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are trying to secure *against*. For information assurance and maintaining an accurate audit history the URL is easier to capture in logs than the body of a request. It is also simpler to parse in a WAF.

To protect against abuse of this information then you might want to make it less obvious. Anyone reading the standard webserver log that uses your first example will be able to see passwords. Your browser will also retain this value in its history and users can create bookmarks containing passwords - neither provides a secure method of storage.

Answer (score 1):

For anything sensitive use POST.

With HTTPS enabled, it is true that query string parameters are encrypted and cannot easily be sniffed. However, GET requests are stored in browser history, and proxy and server logs by default. They can also be leaked in the `referer` header.

POST requests are unlikely to be logged, and do not have the `referer` issue.